# in a word replacer chrome extension, how to highlight the new words and show the replaced words when cursor hovers over it

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have been trying to make a chrome extension that replaces words. While there are many tutorials for that online (https://9to5google.com/2015/06/14/how-to-make-a-chrome-extensions/) , I want to have the replacer words be highlighted and when the cursor moves over it, the word they replaced should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

In broad terms, you should include the modified text in a new node which could be a SPAN.
At this node you will apply a background color of your choice (for example a nice highlighter yellow).
Finally, you will apply the "title" property to the same include tag with the old replaced word.
Good job!